# jQuery/AJAX showing all loaders while typing any field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use [EasyAutocomplete](http://easyautocomplete.com/guide)

jQuery/AJAX showing all loaders while typing any field below is my example code and in the bottom has an example image like currently what happening.

My issue is while I type for job title then showing all loaders like city, on the other hand for the city input as same.

The question is how to show only this loader while I type for this like while I type for job title then want to show loader for job title input filed nor for the city, same as the city.

Perdon me if I didn't explain as well.

```
<form action="/search" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"> 
            <div class="job-search-field">

                <input type="text" name="key" id="key" placeholder="Keyword or Label like: Top,Mid,Entry" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                <i class="icofont icofont-user-search"></i>
                <div class="loader" style="display: none;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 p-l"> 
            <div class="city-field">
                <input type="text" name="city" id="city" placeholder="City" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                <i class="icofont icofont-location-pin"></i>
                <div class="loaderCity" style="display: none;"></div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and the JS

```
$(function(){
    $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        $(".loader").css("display", "block");
    });

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
        $(".loader").css("display", "none");
    });
});

$(function(){
    $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        $(".loaderCity").css("display", "block");
    });

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
        $(".loaderCity").css("display", "none");
    });
});
```

example image

[image]

Comment: Well `$(document).ajaxStart` fires on every single AJAX request your site makes, so you need to either find a way to identify “which” AJAX request it is inside of there, or use a more appropriate handler to begin with - which one that could be, depends on what triggers those AJAX requests in the first place.

Comment: what is the function which calls ajax? I don't see it in your JS code.

Comment: @manhmaluc Thanks! I have used this http://easyautocomplete.com/guide I don't seem `$.ajax` function type of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lets analyze your js code**

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $(".loader").css("display", "block");
  });

  $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $(".loader").css("display", "none");
  });
});

$(function() {
  $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $(".loaderCity").css("display", "block");
  });

  $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $(".loaderCity").css("display", "none");
  });
});
```

`$(document).ajaxStart(function()...` means taht we bind an [`ajaxStart`](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) event to document. And you do it twice.

[`ajaxStart`](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) event fires every time

> Whenever an Ajax request is about to be sent...

So when any Ajax request is about to be sent here is what happens:

Both events triggers (because they are the same) and this is executed:

```
$(".loader").css("display", "block");
$(".loaderCity").css("display", "block");
```

Exactly the same thing happens for [`ajaxComplete`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/) event.

When any Ajax request completes here is what happens:

```
$(".loader").css("display", "none");
$(".loaderCity").css("display", "none");
```

I hope you understand that (because that is what you did)

**Now what is the solution?**

Instead binding an [`ajaxStart`](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) or [`ajaxComplete`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/) events to document it is better to use [`beforeSend`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and [`complete`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) callbacks.

**Example**

```
$.ajax({
  url: "your_url.com",
  ... //all other ajax settings and callbacks
  beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
    $(".loader").css("display", "block");
  },
  complete: function( xhr ) {
    $(".loader").css("display", "none");
  }
});
```

**EDIT**

Since you're using [EasyAutocomplete](http://easyautocomplete.com/guide) you should follow [this section](http://easyautocomplete.com/guide#sec-trigger-event).

There are listed events that you can use.

**So do it like this (Example)**

```
var options = {
  url: "resources/countries.json",
  getValue: "name",
  list: {
    onLoadEvent: function () {
      (".loader").css("display", "block");
    }
    onShowListEvent: function() {
      $(".loader").css("display", "none");
    }   
  }
};

$("#your-id").easyAutocomplete(options);
```

Comment: Thanks! I have used this http://easyautocomplete.com/guide I don't seem `$.ajax` type of code

Comment: Please advise, what can i do

Answer (score 0):

You are calling ajaxStart() function for document, which means if any ajax is started in a page or document, then the inside code will execute.
As per your code

```
$(function(){
    $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        $(".loader").css("display", "block");
    });

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
        $(".loader").css("display", "none");
    });
});

$(function(){
    $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        $(".loaderCity").css("display", "block");
    });

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
        $(".loaderCity").css("display", "none");
    });
});
```

The code

```
$(".loaderCity").css("display", "block");
$(".loader").css("display", "block");
```

will be executed simulataneously as both are called on document ajaxStart.

Instead, you can try individually hiding and showing the loader on your $.ajax codes.

```
// Ajax code for jobsearch.
$.ajax({
   url: 'yourURL',
   type: 'post',
   data: {parameter:data},
   beforeSend: function(){
    // Show image container
        $("#loader").show();
   },
   success: function(response){
       //Your Success code
    },
    complete:function(data){
        // Hide image container
        $("#loader").hide();
    }
 });
```

You can include the beforesend and complete function in your ajax calls for other inputs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I have used this http://easyautocomplete.com/guide I don't seem `$.ajax` type of code

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `$(document).ajaxComplete` to `$(document).ajaxStop`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should start your ajax request at a certain event like when the user is typing in the field with a debouncer(or use [_.debounce(function, wait, [immediate]](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce)).

Some quick code so excuse my mistakes:

```
//When typing in the Keyword input field call the search function 
//after the last keyup event.
$("#key").keyUp(function(event) {
   debounce(search(inputElem), 300);
})

//Function that performs the ajax
function search(inputElem) {
  //From the input element, get the `.loader`
  inputElem.parent().find(".loader").show();
  $.ajax({
    url: "/search",
  }).done(function() {
    //Do something with the response
    //Hide the `.loader`
    inputElem.find(".loader").hide();
  });
}

//Debounce function that executes the given function after a certain time
function debounce(fn, bufferInterval) {
  var timeout;

  return function () {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(fn.apply.bind(fn, this, arguments), bufferInterval);
  };

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have used this http://easyautocomplete.com/guide I don't seem `$.ajax({` type of code

Comment: Please advise, what can i do